# What's the point of this code pattern?

Tags: python

I was trying to create a python wrapper for an tk extension, so I looked at Tkinter.py to learn how to do it.

While looking at that file, I found the following pattern appears a lot of times: an internal method (hinted by the leading "_" in the method name) is defined, then a public method is defined just to be the internal method.

I want to know what's the benefit of doing this.

For example, in the code for class Misc:

```
def _register(self, func, subst=None, needcleanup=1):
    # doc string and implementations is removed since it's not relevant
register = _register
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sometimes, you may want to change a method's behavior.  For example, I could do this (hypothetically within the Misc class):

```
def _another_register(self, func, subst=None, needcleanup=1):
    ...

def change_register(self):
    self.register = self._another_register

def restore_register(self):
    self.register = self._register
```

This can be a pretty handy way to alter the behavior of certain pieces of code without subclassing (but it's generally not advisable to do this kind of thing except within the class itself).

Answer (score 2):

[From PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

In addition, the following special forms using leading or trailing
    underscores are recognized (these can generally be combined with any case
    convention):

> _single_leading_underscore: weak
>   "internal use" indicator.  E.g. "from
>   M   import *" does not import objects
>   whose name starts with an underscore.

Comment: I am guessing, that the author was referring to the external = _external part and not to the whole "underscore" thing. You are correct, anyway.

Comment: OK, but why do you don't name the def accordingly in the first place.

Comment: Well, I am guessing, there could be more of those functions like, say, _register_experimental, _register_debug, _register_stub or anything like that.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm supposing, there could be *another* internal callable, that could've been used, it just didn't make it to the version you have. Generally, I think it is a good idea - you expose one symbol publically and internally it can be anything, a real method, a stubbed out method, a debug version of the method, anything.